# Yeoman Angular Generator source maps/minification issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

When I run `grunt serv:dist` I'm getting a error that is only showing up during minification.

here is the code base: https://github.com/fortitude/fortitude-docs

I can't figure out what is causing the error, and source maps would be ideal right now.

Does anyone know how to get them working?

Thanks!

Comment: For one thing you have use strict at the top of each file. That can seriously burn you. put it inside the controller creation.

Comment: When you minify, it usually gets generated in one file. If not all the code is minify safe, some browsers will not allow the script to run properly.